# Create a new Data.table from another one and match a vector list on one variable

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a data.table with  **2.7 million observations** and **21 variables**  and need to produce a new data.table in which **Variable 1** matches a **vector of values**.

I have vector of values that match with some of Variable1 values, like the following

```
VectorValue=  (A, B, XXZ, UDD...)
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
Table_B <- Table_A[Table_A$Variable1 == VectorValue]
```

or

```
Table_B <- Table_A[Variable1 == VectorValue]
```

but I get this error:

> When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: You might want to work on making a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 Your example is too barebones for me to understand it, anyways.

Comment: can you use `dput(head(Table_A))` to give us a look at data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options I see here:

1. `VectorValue` is the same length as `Table_A$Variable1` and you want to compare values in the same position and return a subset of the data frame where those values are equal. In this case, you may just need to add a comma like so...

`Table_B <- Table_A[Table_A$Variable1 == VectorValue, ]`

...to indicate that you want all *rows* where the condition is `TRUE` and all of the columns in `Table_A`.

2. You want to return any row of `Table_A` where `Table_A$Variable1` has a value that matches *any* value within `VectorValue`. In this case, you'd want to use the `%in%` operator instead of `==`, like so...

`Table_B <- Table_A[Table_A$Variable1 %in% VectorValue, ]`

Comment: Thank you Keith, second option seems good, as VectorValue is not of the same lenght.